# Verify content of nlohmann json which is member of mocked method argument

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock, nlohmann-json

Assume I got a some Message class object which has nlohmann json as private member and public getter:

```
class Message{
public:
  nlohmann::json getJson() { return json_;}
  ...
private:
  nlohmann::json json_;
  ...
};
```

Also there is a class that publishes the message

ex:

```
class Foo {
public:
  publish(const Message& message)
  ...
};
```

In the test I am mocking the `Foo::publish` method and in some scenario I want to check if `json_["key1"]["key2"]` value is different than "" (empty string)

```
EXPECT_CALL(
  *foo_mock_pointer,
  publish(x) // x is the unknown code
);
```

For checking the value of the json object I guess it will be enough:
`testing::Contains(testing::Pair("key1", testing::Pair("key2"), testing::Ne("")))`

But I cant figure out how to get the json from Message object which is the argument of the mocked method.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, it looks like you want to check something about the argument that is passed to your mock function.
You can use `SaveArg` to save that argument inside a variable and then check its value later:

```cpp
Message message;

EXPECT_CALL(
  *foo_mock_pointer,
  publish(x) // x is the unknown code
).WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&message), Return(/*Whatever you want to return*/)));

// Call your class-under-test API here
// ...

// Now check the message:
EXPECT_THAT(message.getJson(), /*Insert your matcher here*/);
```

See here for more info: http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#SaveArgVerify